# Show that $ \sum_{k=0}^{n} \binom{2n+1}{2k} 3^k $ is divisible by $2^n$

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, discrete-mathematics, summation, binomial-coefficients

I want to prove that
$$
 \sum_{k=0}^{n} \binom{2n+1}{2k} 3^k = \sum_{k=0}^{2n} \binom{2n}{k} 3^{\lceil k/2 \rceil}
$$
is divisible by $2^n$.

I tried induction the following way
\begin{align*}
  \sum_{k=0}^{n} \binom{2n+1}{2k} 3^k
   & = \sum_{k=0}^{n} \left( \binom{2n}{2k-1} + \binom{2n}{2k} \right) 3^k \\
   & = \sum_{k=0}^{n} \left( \binom{2n-1}{2k-2} + \binom{2n-1}{2k-1} + \binom{2n-1}{2k-1} + \binom{2n-1}{2k} \right) 3^k \\
   & = 4\cdot \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \binom{2(n-1)+1}{2k} 3^k + 2\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{2n-1}{2k-1} 3^k
\end{align*}
now I can apply the induction hypothesis to the first part, hence the entire first summand is divisible by $2^{n+1}$, if I can show that
$$
 \sum_{k=0}^n \binom{2n-1}{2k-1} 3^k
$$
is divisble by $2^{n-1}$ I would be done. But here I failed.

> So do you have any hints how to show the original claim?

*EDIT*: As mentioned by Will Orrick in the comments, the inductive approach works too, just prove the stronger claim that
$$
 \sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{2n}{2k}3^k, \quad
 \sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{2n+1}{2k}3^k, \quad
 \sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{2n+1}{2k+1}3^k, \quad
 \sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{2n}{2k+1}3^k \quad
$$
are all divisible by $2^n$. If $n = 1$ we get $4$, $10$, $6$ and $2$ and if $n > 1$ we have
\begin{align*}
 & \sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{2n}{2k}3^k \\
 & = 3 \sum_{k=0}^n \binom{2(n-1)+1}{2(k-1)+1} 3^{k-1}
     + \sum_{k=0}^n \binom{2(n-1)+1}{2k} 3^k \\
 & = 3 \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \binom{2(n-1)+1}{2k+1} 3^k + 
       \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \binom{2(n-1)+1}{2k} 3^k \\
 & = 3 \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \binom{2(n-1)}{2k} 3^k + 3 \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \binom{2(n-1)}{2k+1} 3^k
    + \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \binom{2(n-1)}{2k-1} 3^k + \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \binom{2(n-1)}{2k} 3^k \\
 & = 4 \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \binom{2(n-1)}{2k} 3^k + 3 \sum_{k=0}^{n-2} \binom{2(n-1)}{2k+1} 3^k + \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \binom{2(n-1)}{2k-1} 3^k \\
& = 4 \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \binom{2(n-1)}{2k} 3^k + \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \binom{2(n-1)}{2k-1} 3^k + \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \binom{2(n-1)}{2k-1} 3^k \\
& = 4 \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \binom{2(n-1)}{2k} 3^k + 6\sum_{k=0}^{n-2} \binom{2(n-1)}{2k+1} 3^k \\
& = 4 \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \binom{2(n-1)}{2k} 3^k + 6\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \binom{2(n-1)}{2k+1} 3^k  
\end{align*}
and now by assumption both sums are divisible by $2^{n-1}$, and as they are multiplied with even numbers their sum is divisible by $2^n$. Similar
\begin{align*}
 \sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{2n+1}{2k}3^k
 & = \sum_{k=0}^n \left( \binom{2n-1}{2k-2} + \binom{2n-1}{2k-1} + \binom{2n-1}{2k-1} + \binom{2n-1}{2k } \right) 3^k \\
 & = \sum_{k=1}^n \binom{2n-1}{2k-2} 3^k + \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \binom{2n-1}{2k} 3^k + 2\sum_{k=1}^n \binom{2n-1}{2k-1} 3^k \\
 & = 3 \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \binom{2n-1}{2k} 3^k + \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \binom{2n-1}{2k} 3^k + 2\sum_{k=1}^n \binom{2n-1}{2k-1} 3^k \\
& = 4 \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \binom{2n-1}{2k} 3^k +  2\sum_{k=1}^n \binom{2n-1}{2k-1} 3^k \\
& = 4 \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \binom{2(n-1)+1}{2k} 3^k +  6\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \binom{2(n-1)+1}{2k+1} 3^k \\
\end{align*}
and for the other sums we have
\begin{align*}
 \sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{2n+1}{2k+1}3^k
 & = 4 \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \binom{2(n-1)+1}{2k+1} 3^k +  2\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{2n-1}{2k} 3^k\\
 & = 4 \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \binom{2(n-1)+1}{2k+1} 3^k +  2\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \binom{2(n-1)+1}{2k} 3^k\\
 \sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{2n}{2k+1}3^k
 & = 4 \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \binom{2(n-1)}{2k+1} 3^k +  2\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \binom{2(n-1)}{2k} 3^k
\end{align*}
and the induction hypothesis gives the result.

Comment: for your sum on can find $$\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{2n-1}{2k}\cdot 3^k=-\frac{\left(4-2 \sqrt{3}\right)^n+\sqrt{3}
   \left(4-2 \sqrt{3}\right)^n-5 \left(4+2
   \sqrt{3}\right)^n-3 \sqrt{3} \left(4+2
   \sqrt{3}\right)^n}{2 \left(2+\sqrt{3}\right)}$$

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner How do you see this?

Comment: i have a collection of those sums for the university

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner Any reference? And btw your RHS does not like like you can see divisibilty quite easy...

Comment: i will search for some references

Comment: @StefanH This is a classic "thing that can be put into closed form with generating functions", although I haven't actually sat down to do it. The closed form does indeed look pretty unhelpful for integer arithmetic, though.

Comment: I think your approach should work, although I haven't tried it.  There are actually four sums for each $n$, obtained by changing the binomial coefficient in the summand from $\binom{2n+1}{2k}$ to $\binom{2n+1}{2k+1}$, $\binom{2n}{2k}$, or $\binom{2n}{2k+1}$, and all four sums are divisible by $2^n$.  You should be able to make an induction run if you prove these as a set.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let there be a string of $2n$ lights.  Suppose that each light may be off or may shine in one of three colors, red, green, or blue, and that a string of lights is made to shine in a particular color by bracketing it with a pair of control blocks of that color. Suppose further that at most one control block may be inserted between two adjacent lights (also before the first light and after the last light).  Note that control blocks are inserted in same-color pairs, with no control blocks in between, and that it follows from these rules that each string of shining lights must be followed by at least one off light (except at the end).  Some examples are shown below.

`|GG|O|G|O|B|`

`OOO|RR|OO|BBBB|O`

There are $2n+1$ positions at which control blocks may be placed.  There must be an even number, say $2k$, of control blocks, and there are $\binom{2n+1}{2k}$ ways of placing $2k$ control blocks.  There are $3^k$ ways of choosing the colors of the $k$ pairs of adjacent control blocks.  Therefore the total number of configurations for $2n$ lights is
$$
\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{2n+1}{2k}3^k.
$$

Now consider adding two lights at the right end of a string.  If a configuration ends with a control block, there are four ways to extend the configuration,

`...*| + OO`

`...*| + O|R|`

`...*| + O|G|`

`...*| + O|B|`

where * stands for R, G, or B.  One can also move the existing control block one or two units to the right,

`...* + *|O`

`...* + **|`

(All *s take the same value, R, G, or B.)  So there are six ways to extend a configuration that ended in a control block.

If the configuration did not end in a control block, there are $10$ possibilities,

`...O + OO`

`...O + |*|O`

`...O + |**|`

`...O + O|*|`

where, again, * takes one of three values, R, G, B.  Since every configuration of $2n$ lights gives rise to an even number of configurations of $2n+2$ lights, the number of configurations of $2n$ lights is divisible by $2^n$.

Answer (score 5):

$$2S(n)=(1+\sqrt3)^{2n+1}+(1-\sqrt3)^{2n+1}=(4+2\sqrt3)^n(1+\sqrt3)+(4-2\sqrt3)^n(1-\sqrt3)$$

$$\implies S(m+2)-\{(4+2\sqrt3)+(4-2\sqrt3)\}S(m+1)+(4+2\sqrt3)(4-2\sqrt3)S(m)=0$$

Comment: With $S(n) = (1 + \sqrt 3)^{2n+1} + (1 - \sqrt 3)^{2n+1}$ I get $S_{n+2} - 4\cdot S_{n+1} - 4\cdot S_n = 0$, are you sure with your equation?

Comment: @StefanH, Please find the updated answer

Comment: Isn't it that $$\sum_{k=0}^{n} \binom{2n+1}{2k} 3^k = S(n)= \frac{1}{2}\left((1+\sqrt3)^{2n+1}+(1-\sqrt3)^{2n+1}\right)$$ ?

Comment: @RenéGy, Thanks

Answer (score 3):

My approach was to look at the values, see if I can find some pattern. First couple of values are $1,10,76,568,4240,\dots$. You can check that this is a sequence [A107903](https://oeis.org/A107903), and it has known generating function 
$$
f(x)=\frac{1+2x}{1-8x+4x^2}.
$$
Now from this you can easily derive recurrence formula by multiplying both sides by $(1-8x+4x^2)$ and comparing the coefficients (taking $f(x)=\sum a_nx^n$). By this method we get
$$a_0=1,a_1=10$$
$$a_n=8a_{n-1}-4a_{n-2}$$
From this it is quite straight forward to prove the claim by induction.

Only thing that might be a little unclear is how to get that generating function in the first place, and I will think about that, but you could arrive at the recurrence by other means as well (such as assuming there is a linear recurrence and finding its coefficients).

Comment: You wrote a minus before $4x^2$, but it must be plus. I corrected this, thanks for sharing your approach!

Answer (score 2):

I think it's worth pointing out that the standard trick in play here, which gives us the 
$$
\sum_{k=0}^{n} \binom{2n+1}{2k} 3^k = \frac{1}{2}\left((1+\sqrt3)^{2n+1}+(1-\sqrt3)^{2n+1}\right)
$$
formula found in other answers, is to apply the binomial theorem to $(x+y)^n$ and $(x-y)^n$ and add these up. Here, we have
\begin{align}
  (1 + \sqrt3)^{2n+1} &= \sum_{j=0}^{2n+1} \binom{2n+1}{j} 3^{j/2} \\
  (1 - \sqrt3)^{2n+1} &= \sum_{j=0}^{2n+1} \binom{2n+1}{j} (-1)^j 3^{j/2} \\
  (1 + \sqrt3)^{2n+1} + 
  (1 - \sqrt3)^{2n+1} &= \sum_{j=0}^{2n+1} \binom{2n+1}{j} (1 + (-1)^j) 3^{j/2} \\
                      &= 2 \sum_{k=0}^n \binom{2n+1}{2k} 3^k
\end{align}
because $(1 + (-1)^j)$ becomes $0$ for odd $j$ and $2$ for even $j$.

---

Once we have the formula with square roots, we can get a recurrence relation by observing that $1 \pm \sqrt3$ are the roots of $x^2 - 2x - 2 = 0$, so they satisfy $x^2 = 2x+2$ and $x^{n+1} = 2(x^n + x^{n-1})$.

As a result, if $a_n$ is any linear combination of $(1+\sqrt3)^n$ and $(1-\sqrt3)^n$, it also satisfies $a_{n+1} = 2(a_n + a_{n-1})$, and the factor of $2$ in this recurrence accumulates to give us the power of $2^n$ we want. There are a number of ways to turn this into a proof by induction.

Comment: The transition is easy (and maybe you consider it trivial), but the original equation is not a linear combination of your mentioned square roots $1 \pm \sqrt 3$ with polynomial $x^2 = 2x + 2$, instead here $a_n$ is a linear combination of $(1+\sqrt 3)^{2n} = (4+2\sqrt 3)^n$ and $(1-\sqrt 3)^{2n} = (4 - 2\sqrt 3)^n$, and $4 \pm 2\sqrt 3$ are the roots of $x^2 - 8x - 4$, hence we get $a_{n+1} = 8a_n + 4a_{n-1}$ and again a simple induction gives the result. Thanks for sharing your approach!

Comment: @StefanH My idea was that the recurrence $a_{n+1} + 2(a_n + a_{n-1})$ for powers of $(1\pm\sqrt3)^n$ tells us that we pick up a factor of $2$ every *two* steps, so we get a power of $2^n$ when we consider $(1\pm \sqrt3)^{2n+1}$. Considering powers of $(1\pm\sqrt3)^2$ instead, of course, is equivalent.

Answer (score 2):

> We show the following binomial identity for integral $n\geq 0$ is valid:
>   \begin{align*}
> \sum_{k=0}^n\binom{2n+1}{k}3^k=\color{blue}{2^n}\left(\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor n/2 \rfloor}\binom{n}{2k}3^k2^{n-2k}
> +\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor n/2  \rfloor-1}\binom{n}{2k+1}3^{k+1}2^{n-(2k+1)}\right)\tag{1}
> \end{align*}
>   We have a factor $\color{blue}{2^n}$ at the right-hand side of (1). Since the sums in parentheses are non-negative integers the claim follows immediately.

We obtain
\begin{align*}
\color{blue}{\sum_{k=0}^n}&\color{blue}{\binom{2n+1}{2k}3^k}\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{2n+1}\binom{2n+1}{k}(\sqrt{3})^k\frac{1+(-1)^k}{2}\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{k=0}^{2n+1}\binom{2n+1}{k}(\sqrt{3})^k+\frac{1}{2}\sum_{k=0}^{2n+1}\binom{2n+1}{k}(-\sqrt{3})^k\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\left(1+\sqrt{3}\right)^{2n+1}+\frac{1}{2}\left(1-\sqrt{3}\right)^{2n+1}\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\left(1+\sqrt{3}\right)\left(4+2\sqrt{3}\right)^{n}+\frac{1}{2}\left(1-\sqrt{3}\right)\left(4-2\sqrt{3}\right)^{n}\\
&=2^{n-1}\left(1+\sqrt{3}\right)\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}(\sqrt{3})^k2^{n-k}
+2^{n-1}\left(1-\sqrt{3}\right)\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}(-\sqrt{3})^k2^{n-k}\\
&=2^{n}\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}(\sqrt{3})^k2^{n-k}\frac{1+(-1)^k}{2}
+2^{n}\sqrt{3}\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}(-\sqrt{3})^k2^{n-k}\frac{1-(-1)^k}{2}\\
&=2^{n}\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor n/2 \rfloor}\binom{n}{2k}3^k2^{n-2k}
+2^{n}\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor n/2 \rfloor -1}\binom{n}{2k+1}3^{k+1}2^{n-(2k+1)}\\
&\,\,\color{blue}{=2^n\left(\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor n/2 \rfloor}\binom{n}{2k}3^k2^{n-2k}
+\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor n/2 \rfloor-1}\binom{n}{2k+1}3^{k+1}2^{n-(2k+1)}\right)}
\end{align*}
and the claim (1) follows.