# Is it true that $ \sum_{k=0}^{(2q+1)n+q} \binom{2\left((2q+1)n+q\right)+1}{2k} 3^k $ is divisible by $\sum_{k=0}^{q} \binom{2q+1}{2k} 3^k $

Tags: elementary-number-theory, summation, modular-arithmetic, binomial-coefficients

This is a continuation for [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2653050/130022).

Let $$S_q=\sum_{k=0}^{q} \binom{2q+1}{2k} 3^k $$

$$T_q=\sum_{k=0}^{q} \binom{2q+1}{2k+1} 3^k $$.

(i) Is it true that $S_{(2q+1)n+q}$ is divisible by $S_q$, for any natural numbers $n,q$?

The answer for (i) is yes, because we have 
$$ S_{(2q+1)n+q}=S_q\sum_{j\ge0}3^j\binom{2n+1}{2j}S_q^{2(n-j)}T_q^{2j}.$$
Note that since $2nq+n+q$ is a symetric function of ($n,q$), $\  \ S_n$ also divides $S_{(2q+1)n+q}$.

(ii) Is it true that $s_q=\frac{S_q}{2^q}$ and $t_r=\frac{T_r}{2^r}$ are coprime, whatever $q,r$ any natural numbers  ?

EDIT: Thanks to @Steven Stadnicki:

- the sequences $t$ and $s$ can be found at 
  [A001835](https://oeis.org/A001835) and [A001834](https://oeis.org/A001834). They follow the general second order linear recurrence $a_n=4a_{n-1}-a_{n-2}$, with $s_0=t_0=1$ and $t_1=3$ and $s_1=5$.
- $s_{q+1}-2s_q=3t_q$

EDIT 24th Feb. 2018: the answer to question (ii) is yes, as it has been proven [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2664328/130022)

It seems that the prime divisors of the $s$, the prime divisors of the $t$ and the primes that do not divide any $s$ nor any $t$ make a partition of the set of all primes. Moreover, the three classes would have the same density, because it is known** that the prime divisors of the $s$ and those of the $t$ have both density $\frac{1}{3}$.
  **J.C. Lagarias, $\it Pacific \  Journal \ of \ Mathematics$, Vol. 118, No 2, 1985.

Also

(iii) is it true that 
$$\gcd[s_n,s_m]=s_{\frac{1}{2}(\gcd[2n+1,2m+1]-1)}$$
and similarly for $t$?

Comment: When you say 'the same density', how far have you gone out? The strong law of small numbers is very likely to be at play here. The characterization in terms of recurrence relations gets you (1) pretty quickly, I believe, and it also should be able to get you the coprimality of your $s()$ and $t()$ by induction (since those satisfy a much simpler recurrence relation). I'm much more skeptical about the prime partitioning, though.

Comment: @Steven:  if you have a proof that $s$ and $t$ are coprime pairwise, please write it in an answer. I will accept it. The first primes which are divisors of the $t$ are: $3,11,17,41,59,67,83,89,107,113,131,137,139,179,211,227,233,241,251,257,281,283,307$.  For the $s$, we have: $5,19,23,29,43,47,53,71,101,149,163,167,173,191,197,239,263,269,293,311$.                                                                                                            And $  2,7,13,31,37,61,73,79,97,103,109,127,151,157,181,193,199,223,229,271,277$ do not seem to ever divide any $s$ or any $t$.

Comment: Note that these sequences are https://oeis.org/A001834 and https://oeis.org/A001835 (or more accurately a shifted version, https://oeis.org/A079935 ) and that some of the information there (e.g. that $s_{q+1}-2s_q=3t_q$) is definitely relevant to these questions. I suspect now that $s$ and $t$ are coprime for all values (which would imply the prime partitioning, though I missed that earlier) but I'm still less convinced that the density of all three prime sets is equal.

Comment: Thank you @Steven. I will edit my question so as to include these references.